# Cold start in GCP API Gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm seeing request times upwards of 5 seconds whenever the API Gateway is not called for a while and this is only with the API Gateway, calling the backend directly does not cause similar behavior.

I was thinking of creating a Cloud Scheduler job to poll the gateway every now and then and hopefully keep it warm like that. Is there a better way for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a better way. In addition, in the early stage of the Alpha testing of the feature, I noted that the running backend of API Gateway is Cloud Run.

I assume that the behaviour is the same. And Cloud Run offload it's instances after 15 minutes without request. You can request your API Gateway with Cloud Scheduler every 10 minutes. The overcost will be invisible (only 6 call per hour), and should be enough to keep a warm platform.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a better way either. When looking at the [GCP API gateway documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/troubleshoot#high_latency_api_requests) I found this...

> Like Cloud Run and Cloud Functions, API Gateway is subject to "cold start" latency. If your gateway has not received traffic for 15 to 20 minutes, requests made to your gateway within the first 10 to 15 seconds of the cold start will experience 3 to 5 seconds of latency.

So the idea suggested in the question and the answer from Guillaume of using Cloud Scheduler to hit the gateway every 10 minutes worked for me as well.

The reason I am posting another answer is to provide the documentation link, to show how I configured my Cloud Scheduler Job, and to also let people know that they don't need to provide auth for the HTTP request to the API gateway. I was assuming that I needed to provide a way for the Cloud Scheduler Job to properly authenticate through the API gateway, and I also assumed that I needed a valid path in the API gateway config, but I was able to use no auth and an invalid path and it still kept the API gateway alive.

Here is the Job that worked for me:

[image: GCP Cloud Scheduler Job Screenshot]

Notice that the API path I used was /test, which is not a valid path in my API Gateway Config.