# Delay on requests from Google API Gateway to Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-api-gateway

I'm currently seeing delays of 2-3 seconds on my first requests coming into our APIs.
We've set the min instances to 1 to prevent cold start but this a delay is still occurring.

If I check the metrics I don't see any startup latencies in the specified timeframe so I have no insights in what is causing these delays. Tracing gives the following:

[image: Tracing details GET /info]

The only thing I can change, is switching to "CPU is always allocated" but this isn't helping in any way.

Can somebody give more information on this?

Comment: Have you tried a different region for your API Gateway? We have no significant delays between API Gateway and Cloud Run.

Comment: Hey OP, also experiencing this. Did the uptime check help?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69360312/15774176) :

As per [doc](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/3-ways-optimize-cloud-run-response-times) :

> Idle instances As traffic fluctuates, Cloud Run attempts to reduce the
> chance of cold starts by keeping some idle instances around to handle
> spikes in traffic. For example, when a container instance has finished
> handling requests, it might remain idle for a period of time in case
> another request needs to be handled.
>
> Cloud Run But, Cloud Run will terminate unused containers after some
> time if no requests need to be handled. This means a cold start can
> still occur. Container instances are scaled as needed, and it will
> initialize the execution environment completely. While you can keep
> idle instances permanently available using the min-instance setting,
> this incurs cost even when the service is not actively serving
> requests.
>
> **So, let’s say you want to minimize both cost and response time latency**
> **during a possible cold start. You don’t want to set a minimum number**
> **of idle instances, but you also know any additional computation needed**
> **upon container startup before it can start listening to requests means**
> **longer load times and latency.**
>
> Cloud Run container startup  There are a few tricks you can do to
> optimize your service for container startup times. The goal here is to
> minimize the latency that delays a container instance from serving
> requests. But first, let’s review the Cloud Run container startup
> routine.
>
> When Starting the service
>
> - Starting the container
> - Running the entrypoint command to start your    server
> - Checking for the open service port
>
> **You want to tune your service to minimize the time needed for step 1a.**
> **Let’s walk through 3 ways to optimize your service for Cloud Run**
> **response times.**
>
> **1. Create a leaner service**
> **2. Use a leaner base image**
> **3. Use global variables**

As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#background-activity) :

> Background activity is anything that happens after your HTTP response
> has been delivered. To determine whether there is background activity
> in your service that is not readily apparent, check your logs for
> anything that is logged after the entry for the HTTP request.
>
> **Avoid background activities if CPU is allocated only during request processing**
>
> If you need to set your service to [allocate CPU only during request
> processing](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation), when the Cloud Run service finishes handling a
> request, the container instance's access to CPU will be disabled or
> severely limited. You should not start background threads or routines
> that run outside the scope of the request handlers if you use this
> type of CPU allocation. Review your code to make sure all asynchronous
> operations finish before you deliver your response.
>
> Running background threads with this kind of CPU allocation can create
> unpredictable behavior because any subsequent request to the same
> container instance resumes any suspended background activity.

As mentioned in the [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69727336/15774176) reason could be that all the operations you performed have happened  after the response is sent.

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#background-activity) the CPU is allocated only during the request processing by default so the only thing you have to change is to enable CPU allocation for background activities.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/3-ways-optimize-cloud-run-response-times) for more information related to the steps to optimize Cloud Run response times.
You can also have a look on the [blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-use-google-api-gateway-with-cloud-run-60698959b342) related to use of  Google API Gateway with Cloud Run.

Comment: The delay is occuring for HTTP requests so no background related tasks. This comment doesn't really help on the question that I have. I'm now trying to solve this with a HTTP uptime check to prevent end users of having this initial delay.

Comment: can you briefly explain the issue you are facing and can you see anything in logs? it will be helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: I've defined a simple endpoint /info on Cloud Run. This endpoint occasionally has a delay of 2-3 seconds. I would expect that this doesn't occur with minimal instances set to one. Normal response time is 200-300ms.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this thread?

[Cold start in GCP API Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027399/cold-start-in-gcp-api-gateway)

set a cloud scheduler that call your api gateway each 10 min might help.